# When inheriting from an abstract class to create another abstract class should I redeclare all virtual functions?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

This is more of a preferred style question when working in c++. I am looking for preferred standards around this.

Say I have an interface A

```
class AInterface {
public:
    virtual ~AInterface() = default;
    virtual void a() = 0;
};
```

And then I have another interface B that is built on top on A

```
class BInterface : public AInterface{
public:
    virtual void b() = 0;
    virtual void otherb() = 0;
};
```

My question is should I redeclare all the virtual functions from AInterface in B like so?

```
class BInterface : public AInterface{
public:
    virtual void a() = 0;
    virtual void b() = 0;
    virtual void otherb() = 0;
};
```

Comment: Re-declaration (without `override`/`final`) is subject to typo.

Comment: Why would you want to increase clutter? But at least if you override a declaration, use `override`.

Comment: I don't believe redeclaring them has any functional impact. But it can help users by providing a single point of lookup to see what needs to be implemented. On the other hand, it's a repetition which is generally not desirable. It's a judgement call, and not very impactful.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It's a potential breaking change from the ABI POV. It can make vtables larger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You do not have to.

...and you should not, because it is unnecessary duplication without benefit. If you do, at least use the `override` keyword to avoid a mismatch in the declarations.

Imagine you change the base to

```
class AInterface {
public:
    virtual ~AInterface() = default;
    virtual void a(int) = 0;
};
```

and you forget to update `BInterface`, then whoops, now you have a `void a()` in `BInterface` that was not intended. If however you have `override`:

```
class BInterface : public AInterface{
public:
    virtual void a() override = 0;
    virtual void b() = 0;
    virtual void otherb() = 0;
};
```

You would get a compiler error, because after the above refactoring `void a()` does not override a method from its base.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

you would only re declare/define the virtual functions in subsequent classes if you intend to change their functionality from that of the base class. that said the examples you've given are both pure virtual classes so you wouldn't be able to instantiate them. But in general, one of the points of inheritance is that you don't have to continuously re-declare functions that do the same thing for derived classes.